# why recursive function taking latest value while returning back?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int fun(int ,int);
main()
{
        int res;
        res=fun(2,4);
        printf("in main() res=%d\n",res);
}
int fun(int x,int n)
{
        int val=1;
        val=1;
        if(n>0)
        {
                if(n%2==1)
                        val=val*x;
                val=val*fun(x*x,n/2);
        }
}
```

i middle i'm getting val=16, when val=val*x is executed ,but while returning its not taking that value ?? why its taking latest value of that variable when returning back ?

Comment: I'm missing the return statement from fun.

Comment: fun() is not returning anything.

Comment: Your compiler was made by dinosaurs. As cool as that might sound, I would suggest upgrading to one which isn't older than 15 years.

Comment: without return statement also giving output ,anyhow after n>0 condition fails control will goes to main()

Comment: ok when i'm using return val; that output i understand but why its giving 4096 when i'm not giving return statement ??

Comment: because it is undefined behavior. you drop of the end of a function without returning a value, anything can happen

Comment: @achalsingh Because the program goes haywire if you don't. It is undefined behavior - anything can happen.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings! Actually your compiler should warn by default already. If it does not, get a proper one. Best one which at least knows C99 and warns about non-prototype-style function declarators and invalid `main` signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must `return` the desired result in the function, the last line should be:

```
return val;
```

You should be getting compiler diagnostics for this.

Answer (score 3):

> but while returning its not taking that value ??

It is because, you're not returning **val** from *fun()*. You should be warned by the compiler, unless compiler warning is turned off.

You need to add a return statement to your func which is declared to return an integer. Also, you seem to reset Val every time. I'm not sure what do you intend to do.

The code will look like

```
int fun(int x,int n)
{
  int val=1;
  //val=1; // WhY do you need this? this will reset Val everytime

  if(n) //n>0 is not required as if evaluates to true if it is not zero
  {
    if(n%2==1)
    val=val*x;
    val=val*fun(x*x,n/2);
  }
  return val;
}
```